# Types of artwork to include in portfolio?

Tags: branding, portfolio, marketing

I am currently employed as a Graphic designer in an IT company and want to switch to a company that is more focused on brand or design.

I plan to make a new portfolio. What types of work are relevant to the following topics 1. design, 2. brand or 3. marketing?

Comment: You might want to clarify on "design". There's visual design, ui design, product design, not to mention mobile, web or print. As you can see a portfolio focused on those directions might guide what work you put in your portfolio

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty broad skill set, so I face a similar problem in portfolio development.

In my portfolio, I choose to emphasize the skills that:

1. **I love** (interaction design, prototypes, branding)
2. **I think will get me hired or offered jobs** (marketing, analytics, mailchimp campaigns, etc.)
3. **Make me unique** (photography, latte-making skills)

[My personal website](http://ashleepalka.com) divides **collections of projects into categories** on the main page. I have one for personal branding (stuff I do for free for me and my friends), one for corporate branding, one for mailchimp and so on. Those are all accessible from the main page.

**When actually applying for a job**, I pull out the content that's most relevant to the position that I want. Sometimes that's something from every category, but often it's just one or two categories.

When the employer googles me or visits my website, they get a taste of all that I can do. Just keep in mind that when you actually send people material, you don't want to appear to be a Jack of all trades (which is why you should **curate your content**).

---

Hopefully this helps you out. If you honestly don't want to get hired for graphic design jobs, you might consider leaving them off your portfolio entirely. But, to me, that seems like a great skill that might help you get hired for a more marketing/branding type of job.

Answer (score 0):

1. design

This term is broad, but I'd probably add a font that I have designed. This shows: 1) I have technical skills 2) I have typographic understanding 3) I have design skills (the font must be good looking)

2. brand

The portfolio could contain shots of a logo you designed, on physical objects, such as coffee mugs and stuff.

3. marketing

Again, this is a broad term, but I'd try to display some work I've done for big companies. Logos, web design stuff, print stuff, anything that has a known company logo on it. That means that big companies (or agencies) trusted you for their marketing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, include images/projects that are as close as possible to the kind of work you want to do. If you don't have much, it's a good idea to make some, even if they're not real projects. (A place like [briefbox](https://briefbox.me/) can help give you some prompts).

If you have specific companies you wast to apply to, research the kind of work they do and highlight similar work in your portfolio